# How to create a datatype with limited set of possibilities to switch on its value?

Tags: swift, struct, enums

I would like to pass a value to a function that lets me pick which value to set from a set list.  An example of using this would be a function that needs to behave differently based on the "mode" that the page is in like creating a new post or editing an existing one.  I currently am doing this by passing a string parameter into the function with "new" or "edit" in the string.  I thought the right way to do this was to create an enum so that the value that is passed is that enum type and I don't have to worry about a typo breaking the app.

I thought I just had to declare an enum with my options as cases and then could just use it like you would a customer data type.  That didn't work for me and either I am making a silly mistake or this wasn't how this is supposed to be used.

```
// -------------
// Current Code
func filterBySwitch(filterOption: String){
    print("You asked me to filter by \(filterOption)")
}
filterBySwitch(filterOption: "userOwns")

// -------------
// I though this is how I would pass the argument when only 3 available options
enum filterType {
    case userHeart
    case userOwns
    case userSeen
}
func filterBySwitch(filterOption: filterType){
    print("You asked me to filter by \(filterType)")
}
filterBySwitch(filterOption: .userOwns)
```

Comment: In what way isn't the 2nd set of code working for you? Be specific (in your question, don't reply in a comment).

Comment: What do you mean by "that didn't work"?

Comment: So you want your `filterBySwitch` to do different tasks based on `filterType`? What didn't work for you exactly using enums? BTW, you declare enums capitalized, just like how you declare your classes.

Comment: Did you mean to say `print("You asked me to filter by \(filterOption)")`? You wrote `filterType` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to do something like this:

```
enum FilterType {
    case userHeart
    case userOwns
    case userSeen
}
func filterBySwitch(filterOption: FilterType){
    print("You asked me to filter by \(filterOption)") //<-
}
filterBySwitch(filterOption: .userOwns)
```

In Swift, you use capitalized identifier for type, such convention will help you find such mistakes easier.